# Can't use TimeZone or TimeZoneInfo as property (Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, properties, timezone

I am trying to set a TimeZone or TimeZoneInfo as property for 1 of my Entities but I can't seem to make it work and I don't understand why. Purpose is to store what TimeZone this Entity has (user based choice). Whenever the Entity Framework is trying to map and create the Model based on the Classes (Code First approach) it throw's an error.

**If I map it as a Type "TimeZone" than I get this when starting my WebApp:**

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: entitySet

**If I map it as a Type "TimeZoneInfo" than I get this when starting my WebApp:**

> (151,10) : error 3004: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 151:
>                    No mapping specified for properties MyEntityName.
>                    TimezoneInfo in Set MyEntityNames. An Entity with Key (PK) will not round-trip when:
>                    Entity is type [ProjectName.Models.MyEntityName]

EDIT:
I also tried get/setting it but same result:

```
 private TimeZoneInfo timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.Local;

 // does not work
 public TimeZoneInfo TimezoneInfo  
 {
     get => timeZone;
     set => timeZone = value;
 }
 public TimeZoneInfo TimezoneInfo { get; set; } // does not work
 public TimeZone Timezone { get; set; } // does not work
```

I could use the `Id` of the `TimeZoneInfo` and map it, generate it in the UI for selection but I really wonder why this doesn't work.

Can anyone shed light on this please?
Thank you!

Comment: When you parse a date string there is no implied timezone.  When there is no timezone the application uses the PC timezone but doesn't fill in the TimeZoneInfo.   So in the Get/Set Property in your class insert the Local Timezone.

Comment: Thank you @jdweng, I didn't mentioned it that I tried that as well but same result as in error nr 2. Or am I doing it "wrong"?

Comment: I don't have enough info to help.

Comment: I have edited the original post if you didn't see it. I really am not doing anything more than that, if i comment that property out, it works, if not it doesn't. What info can I provide more, tell me and I will.

Comment: Re edited the post with a little more info.

Comment: I wouldn't particularly expect to be able to store a whole TimeZoneInfo in the database, nor would I suggest it's a good idea, to be honest - I think using an ID would be a better option. You might want to consider using an IANA ID (e.g. Europe/London) instead of a Windows ID, to make it more feasible to use the database from non-Windows applications.

Comment: Alright, makes sense but I'm still intrigued on why it doesn't work ... Thank you for the IANA tip, will look into that!